# How do I generate a random time interval and add it to a mysql datetime using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have many rows in mysql table with datetime's in the format of:

```
2008-12-08 04:16:51 etc
```

I'd like to generate a random time interval of anywhere between 30 seconds, and 3 days and add them to the time above.

a) how do I generate a random time between 30 and 3 days?

b) how do I add this time to the date time format above?

I imagine i need to do a loop to pull out all the info, do the math in php, and then update the row...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easier way.

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('2008-12-08 04:16:51 +'.rand(30, 60 * 60 * 24 * 3).' seconds'));
```

Comment: wow... i was trying $rand_sec = rand(1,60);
  
  $rand_min = rand(1,60);
  
  $rand_hour = rand(1,12);
  
  $rand_day = rand(1,30);
  
  
  $conf_time = strtotime('+ ' . $rand_day . ' day ' . $rand_hour . ' hours ' . $rand_min . ' minutes . ' . $rand_sec . ' seconds', $row['dateAdded']);
  but it didn't work unlike yours. thanks!

Comment: strangely i noticed however some dates managed to calculate a time earlier than the original time... which seems impossible to me?? ie 2008-12-08 04:16:36 was 1 original time, and the calculated 2nd time came out as 2008-12-08 04:13:16. how is that so?

Comment: hmm odd. maybe having a relative and compound format in the same string is messing it up. you could try this though $new_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+'.rand(30, 60 * 60 * 24 * 3).' seconds', strtotime('2008-12-08 04:16:51')));

Comment: hmmm... thanks for that... i am still getting the ocasional time less than the original. this IS odd!

Comment: out of 23,000 rows, 2,000 roughly have a 2nd time less than the 1st.

Comment: ok, i've added a rule to the query loop where 2nd time < 1st time and just rerun the script several times until there were none left... I find it really weird.. i think this solution should have worked. thanks !

Comment: this is very strange. i would very much like to figure out what is happening here.

Answer (score 9):

Using MySQL's rand() function:

```
update [table] set [field] = now() + interval floor(rand()*(60*60*24*3)) second;
```

wil get you the current datetime + between *0* seconds and three days.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to use a random unix timestamp and convert into the MySQL timestamp format?
I would assume you could so something like:

```
$randomTime = time() + rand( 30, 86400 * 3 );   // since there are 86400 seconds in a day,
                                                        // this should generate a random time
                                                        // 3-30 days from now
$randomTimeString = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $randomTime ); // format the date (php.net/date)
$st = $mysqli->query( "...", $randomTimeString );       // insert it into the database
...
```

This probably isn't the most efficient solution, but it should work.

Comment: Note - the OP asked for 'between 30 seconds and 3 days', not 3-30 days.

Comment: Heh, didn't notice that. Fixed it though.