# PHP random date and multiple dates

Tags: php, random

I have a problem regarding randoming a PHP date like this 2013-09-18 12:30.
I want to random 6 dates like that one for 6 users, so dates don't mix (dates can be the same but time must be +/- few hours). 
To random date i used:

```
    <?php 
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days')); 
    ?>
```

and had success with it but i can random hours or minutes (seconds i don't need). 
The page is for reserving appointments for patients and giving them random therapy dates. I also have an eventCalendar to show dates.

P.S is it possible to input multiple dates like an array (date1, date2, date3) and show in mysql table i always get 0000-00-00.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about to run a **for LOOP** with limit 6  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698287/how-do-i-generate-a-random-time-interval-and-add-it-to-a-mysql-datetime-using-ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add random number of hours to your string for `strtotime`, can do same for minutes

**With Hours**

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days '.mt_rand(9,17). 'Hours' )); 
?>
```

**With Hours and Minutes**

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days '.mt_rand(9,17). 'Hours '.mt_rand(0,30). 'Minutes' )); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days')); 
for ($i = 0; $i < 6;$i++){
   $hour = str_pad(mt_rand(0,23), 2, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    $min = str_pad(mt_rand(0,59), 2, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $date . ' '. $hour .':'.$min .'<br>'; 
}
?>
```

with making query and different dates (should work):

```
<?
    $insert = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7;$i++){
       $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days')); 
       $hour = str_pad(mt_rand(0,23), 2, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $min = str_pad(mt_rand(0,59), 2, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $dateTime =  $date . ' '. $hour .':'.$min ; 
        $insert .= "('".$dateTime."'),";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO tableName (dateField) VALUES ". substr($insert,0,-1);
    echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that was one part of the problem solved but i need to put date in for loop to get 7 different dates like this i will get only 1 repeated 7 times in this case. Otherwise nice and quick answer :D

Comment: If You want different dates, just put: $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,31).' days'));  into FOR loop.