# PHP: convert date to datetime and insert it into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have an input field in my html page that gets **Date** from jQuery datepicker.

The format looks like this:

```
18/02/2017
```

I have a MYSQL field which is `DATETIME`

I need to insert the Date above into this MYSQL field.

So i tried this code:

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['php_date']));
```

but the result of `$mysqlDate` is this:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: date("Y-m-d", strtotime($your_date) and try, I means remove his

Comment: @rahul_m, still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing,

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$_POST['php_date'])));
echo $mysqlDate;
```

Give it a try,

it should work.

***Note:
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.***

Source [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Your new concern answer,

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$_POST['php_date']).' + '.rand(30,60*60*24*3).' seconds'));
```

Comment: nice one... that did the trick. is there any way to add a random hour and minute to the $mysqlDate ?

Comment: Mate, your concern has been solved, as for question. Create new question regarding your this new problem , I assure you I will be there too. :)

Comment: Thanks ! If my answer solved your problem, you can accept my answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: will do.. its saying I need to wait for 2 minutes before I can accept it... :)

Comment: my heart not accepting this, check edit section of answer for your new concern. Thanks

Comment: I just did the exact same thing.. lol.. found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698287/how-do-i-generate-a-random-time-interval-and-add-it-to-a-mysql-datetime-using-ph    Thanks anyway mate.. appreciate your help...

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the posted date to a

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Format before converting it into date time.

You can do

```
$date=$_POST['php_date'];
list($day,$month,$year)=explode('/', $date);
$date=$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

And then use `$date`.

Comment: *si ricorda*, the delimiter comes "primo" with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) ;-) I fixed that. Otherwise, they'd be a conversion to string error.

Comment: Thanks mate! Didn't notice the mistake! :)